# Understanding where to put the IPN reciever function in django-paypal

Tags: django, paypal, django-views, django-paypal

I have a similar issue to the  post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-users/django-paypal%7Csort:date/django-users/ZUBd-vcyjrs/e06tW_EfEQAJ) in regards to setting up the receiver function for the paypal-ipn

What we are trying to do(I don't know this other person but I assume we stand together on this topic) is to understand how to deduce a path to receiving a paypal IPN signal in which we then can update the django database.

I have implemented the django-paypal API by following the directions [here](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html)

Overall what I do is I create a view in my views.py as follows

```
def payment_page(request):
   """This fucntion returns payment page for the form"""
   if not request.session.get('form-submitted', False):
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('grap_main:error_page'))
   else:
       amount = set_payment()
       paypal_dict = {
           "business": "business@gmail.com",
           "amount": str(amount),
           "item_name": "2017 USGF Championships",
           "notify_url": "https://15b6b6cb.ngrok.io" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),
           "return_url": "https://15b6b6cb.ngrok.io/Confirm",
           "cancel_return": "https://15b6b6cb.ngrok.io/RegistrationForm",

  }
       form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
       context = confirm_information()
       context["amount"] = amount
       context["form"] = form
       request.session['form-submitted'] = False
       valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
       return render(request, "grap_main/payment.html", context)
```

Where my then I have payment.html which then create the paypal button simply by using the line as advised in the documentation

`{{ form.render }}`

Now I can receive a POST to the paypal url that I specified in the documentation however I don't know where I should put my signal function that will grab the IPNs once someone has completed a purchase.

```
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
   """signal function"""
   ipn_obj = sender
   if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
       print 'working'
   else:
       print "not working"
```

Right now I am calling this function in the view payment_page() however I know this is before the POST to the paypal and is not correct 
I don't understand where I should call the show_me_the_money() function. I am used to creating a views in which is called from the html script as shown below

```
def register(request):
   """aquire information from new entry"""
   if request.method != 'POST':
       form = RegisterForm()
   else:
       if 'refill' in request.POST:
           form = RegisterForm()
       else:
           form = RegisterForm(data=request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               request.session['form-submitted'] = True
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('grap_main:payment_page'))
```

.html

```
<form action="{% url 'grap_main:register' %}" method='post' class="form">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% bootstrap_form form %}
     <br>
     {% buttons %}
     <center>
       <button name='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </center>
     {% endbuttons %}
   </form>
```

I believe I need to call the function after a person has completed a purchase however I don't know how to target that time window in my code. I want to make sure I handle a case in which the user once there are done paying don't always return to the merchant site.

Any help on this subject would not only benefit me but also the earlier poster. I hope to make a tutorial when I figure this out to help others that might get stuck as well.

Please note that I have also use ngrok to make sure my project is accessible to the paypal IPN service. I am using two urls.py files as well, i which the main one looks as so

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'', include('grap_main.urls', namespace='grap_main')),
]
```

where the 'grap_main.urls' are all the specific views for my site, ex.

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^Confirm', views.confirm, name='confirm'),
   url(r'^Events', views.events, name='events'),
   .........]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**: Forgot to mention where and how to put the code that you wrote (the handler if you like). Inside the `handlers.py` file write it like this:

```
# grap_main/signals/handlers.py

from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received, invalid_ipn_received

@receiver(valid_ipn_received)
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    """Do things here upon a valid IPN message received"""
    ...

@receiver(invalid_ipn_received)
def do_not_show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    """Do things here upon an invalid IPN message received"""
    ...
```

Although signals (and handlers) can live anywhere, a nice convention is to store them inside your app's `signals` dir. Thus, the structure of your `grap_main` app should look like this:

```
project/
    grap_main/
        apps.py
        models.py
        views.py
        ...
        migrations/
        signals/
            __init__.py
            signals.py
            handlers.py
```

Now, in order for the `handlers` to be loaded, write (or add) this inside `grap_main/apps.py`

```
# apps.py

from django.apps.config import AppConfig


class GrapMainConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'grapmain'
    verbose_name = 'grap main' # this name will display in the Admin. You may translate this value if you want using ugettex_lazy

    def ready(self):
        import grap_main.signals.handlers
```

Finally, in your `settings.py` file, under the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, instead of `'grap_main'` use this:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... # other apps here
    'grap_main.apps.GrapMainConfig',
    ... # other apps here
]
```

*Some side notes*:

1. Instead of using standard forms to render the paypal button use [encrypted buttons](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/encrypted_buttons.html). That way you will prevent any potential modification of the form (mostly change of prices).
2. I was exactly in your track a few months ago using the terrific `django-paypal` package. However, I needed to upgrade my project to Python 3. But because I used the `encrypted buttons` I was unable to upgrade. Why? Because encrypted buttons depend on `M2Crypto` which doesn't support (yet) Python 3. What did I so? I dropped `django-paypal` and joined [`Braintree`](https://www.braintreepayments.com/en-gr) which is a PayPal company. Now, not only I can accept PayPal payments but also credit card ones. All Python 3!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still confused on how the overall process of the what is going on.  When I create the `handlers.py` and `singals.py` what exactly goes in there? I am guessing in my signals I put `show_me_the_money` function but not sure what goes in `handlers.py`. I am also confused how my program grabs the IPN messages from paypal. Once again thanks for your reply

Comment: @MichaelG. Yes you should place this function under the `handlers.py` file. Forgot to mention that :/. I'll update my answer!

Comment: Hi @nik_m, take a look at this question also, please!                                     See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176022/perform-custom-logic-after-django-paypal-successful-transaction) question, please!

Answer (score 0):

This is is embarrassing but the problem was that I was not using a test business account... I implemented the answer nik_m suggegested as well so I would advise doing the same. Put the function:

```
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
   """signal function"""
   ipn_obj = sender
   if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
       print 'working'
   else:
       print "not working"



valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

in `handlers.py`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope things are working for you now.

Comment: Hi @nik_m, can you help me regarding this topic? please!                          Here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176022/perform-custom-logic-after-django-paypal-successful-transaction